# Web server to multiple ejb server call using tomee

Tags: cluster-computing, ejb-3.0, apache-tomee, iiop

I am using TomEE server and i want to deploy my ejb application to multiple instances and want to access it using a web application. 
I want to add a load balancer between web application and ejb application.
How can i achieve this.

I already have a load balancer for web application multiple instances using mod_jk,but i need this configuration somewhere in INITIALCONTEXT properties file.

Attaching a pic of how i want to build my app architecture.[architecture pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQVRd.png)

I'm struggling in this from quite some time. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: these instances can be on different servers also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use TOMEE multipoint discovery feature using failover in initial context PROVIDER URL and give multiple URL.
multipoint.properties file we add in conf.

Comment: http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/want-to-use-load-balancer-while-doing-lookup-so-that-request-can-go-to-multiple-instances-for-EJB-td4682595.html